# Copy and store the contents in parentheses with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In text file, contents are sorted as...

"ABC (**990103**)

EFG (**131101**)"

I wanna copy those every lines of **numbers** in parentheses and paste them to new text file.

It seems like possible with search and replace function but i still need to know how to use it in this case, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the match:

```
^.*\((\d+)\)$
```

And replace with:

```
$1
```

This works because:

1. Match from the beginning of the line with `^`
2. Match everything until a paren `.*\(`, the paren is escaped because it is special
3. Use a group `()` to match some text and save for later.
4. Match one or more digits `\d+`
5. The digits are followed by a close paren `\)`
6. ... which is at the end of the line `$`

Then the replacement `$1` is the first group match in the regex, everything inside of the un-escaped parens.